# Linux kernel function set_user_nice

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, scheduling, scheduler

I have an homework assignment, we need to add some features to Linux kernel, and we're working on red hat 2.4.18.
I looked in sched.c, function set_user_nice:

```
void set_user_nice(task_t *p, long nice)
{
    unsigned long flags;
    prio_array_t *array;
    runqueue_t *rq;

    if (TASK_NICE(p) == nice || nice < -20 || nice > 19)
        return;
    /*
     * We have to be careful, if called from sys_setpriority(),
     * the task might be in the middle of scheduling on another CPU.
     */
    rq = task_rq_lock(p, &flags);
    if (rt_task(p)) {
        p->static_prio = NICE_TO_PRIO(nice);
        goto out_unlock;
    }
    array = p->array;
    if (array)
        dequeue_task(p, array);
    p->static_prio = NICE_TO_PRIO(nice);
    p->prio = NICE_TO_PRIO(nice);
    if (array) {
        enqueue_task(p, array);
        /*
         * If the task is running and lowered its priority,
         * or increased its priority then reschedule its CPU:
         */
        if ((NICE_TO_PRIO(nice) < p->static_prio) || (p == rq->curr))
            resched_task(rq->curr);
    }
out_unlock:
    task_rq_unlock(rq, &flags);
}
```

I don't understand what exactly the code checks in the last if statement,
because few lines above it, we have this line:

```
p->static_prio = NICE_TO_PRIO(nice);
```

and then, in the if statement we check:

```
(NICE_TO_PRIO(nice) < p->static_prio)
```

Am I missing something?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I looked for this function in a newer source code, and this function implemented in kernel/sched/core.c.
The part I was talking about:

```
             old_prio = p->prio;
3585         p->prio = effective_prio(p);
3586         delta = p->prio - old_prio;
3587 
3588         if (queued) {
3589                 enqueue_task(rq, p, ENQUEUE_RESTORE);
3590                 /*
3591                  * If the task increased its priority or is running and
3592                  * lowered its priority, then reschedule its CPU:
3593                  */
3594                 if (delta < 0 || (delta > 0 && task_running(rq, p)))
3595                         resched_curr(rq);
3596         }
3597 out_unlock:
```

So it does seem like now the diff between the old and the new priority calculated properly.

Answer (score 0):

Is 2.4.18 the kernel version?   I'm looking at that source and don't see set_user_nice in sched.c.

Anyways, I think that they're handling a race condition there.  It's possible between the time they set the new process priority, the process itself has changed it.  So they're checking if that's the case and re-scheduling the task if so.

Comment: I think it wasn't the case. It seems like a bug to me. I added the newer source code of this part in my answer